# mvc4 dynamically generated fields missing from form post

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a somewhat odd situation where I have dynamically generated fields on a form--all dropdown lists. The selections correspond to binary values that I want to sum together to form a bitmask. I'm generating the dropdowns this way:

```
<table class="center">
    @foreach (var field in Model.Fields)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@field.DisplayText:</td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownList(field.FieldName, new SelectList(field.Options, "FlagValue", "Text", field.SelectedValue), "(doesn't matter)")                
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

This seems to work--as far as rendering the proper HTML in the view. But my controller is not receiving the selections in the fields. I tried this to loop through the dynamic fields.

In the code below, PatientSelectorEditor is my ViewModel.

```
    private void GetFlagInfo(PatientSelectorEditor pse, out string description, out long flags)
    {
        description = null;
        flags = 0;

        // get list of all possible fields that could be in the view.
        pse.Fields = InitPatientSelectorFields(0);
        foreach (PriceFlagField field in pse.Fields)
        {                
            foreach (var option in field.Options)
            {
                // was something selected here?
                if (Request[field.FieldName].Equals(option.FlagValue))
                {
                    description += ", " + option.Text;
                    flags += option.FlagValue;
                }
            }                
        }            
    }
```

The line that goes

```
 Request[field.Name]
```

is not finding the dynamically generated fields in my view.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you included you Dropdownlist inside form tag ?

Comment: Please post your full html for that page so we can analyse it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong here. This line....

```
if (Request[field.FieldName].Equals(option.FlagValue))
```

needed an explicit string comparison like this

```
if (Request[field.FieldName].Equals(option.FlagValue.ToString()))
```